# Record created in test class is not visible in controller

Tags: testing, salesforce, apex, test-class

I am creating a test class for a controller and i dont know for what reason a record created for a object is not visible in a method in controller.That method is having a select query which is giving the blank output. If i run the same query in test class , that is giving me the output. Rest of the records for different objects are also visible and working fine.

Is there any specific reason why the record is not available in a method in a controller??

Comment: Please check you sharing settings.

Comment: You created the record, but did you insert it in the db?  Please consider showing at least your test class here.

Answer (score 0):

**Check 1:**

It might be some access issue. So check the `Object` access in the `Profile` level.

If you are a System Admin, then try to create records by running as System Admin user.

```
User adminUser = [SELECT Id,Name FROM User WHERE Id =: UserInfo.getUserId()];
System.runAs(adminUser){
    //Test Class block
}
```

**Check 2:**

If it is happening in a `Trigger` or `Trigger_handler` related `Test Class`. Then please see the below scenario.

**Ex:** Assume, you are working on `Order` and `OrderItem` objects. You have a trigger on `Order` object (`after insert` or `after update`).

To create any `OrderItem`, you first need the `Order` to be created. So you will insert an Order first and then OrderItem follows.

Since we have a trigger on `Order` object, the `trigger` will start to execute as soon as we insert the Order record.
In trigger we may have used the `OrderItem` records also. But they will **not be available in Trigger yet**.

Because, we have **only created the `Order` record so far** and the trigger started executing immediately and we are yet to create the OrderItem.

So, try the below approach:

```
Create/Insert an Order.
Create OrderItems by using the above Order id.
Now just do a simple update on Order record and see if it works.
```